# Derivative of $e^{x}* e^{ix}$ using product rule

Tags: calculus

Derivative of $e^{x} \times e^{ix}$.

This can be written as $D(e^{(1+i)x})$.

Using the chain rule $e^{(1+i)x} \times D((1+i)x) = (1+i)e^{(1+i)x}$

But using the product rule:

Using the product rule $D(e^{(1+i)x}) = D(e^{x} \times e^{ix}) = e^{x} \times ie^{ix} + e^{x} \times e^{ix}$ but I don't see how this is the same...

Comment: In your product rule first term should be $e^x \times ie^{ix}$

Comment: How is $D(e^{ix})=(1+i)e^{(1+i)x}$?? (oops, ninja'd)

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Comment: Is it now trivial?

Comment: Yes very appearant!